# Problem with declaring new command containing number

Tags: macros

I am trying to declare a new command using the following string:

```
\newcommand{\to8}[1]{\xrightarrow{\mathmakebox[0.8cm]{#1}}}
```

but the compiler returns many errors.  I just don't understand why if I write

```
\xrightarrow{\mathmakebox[0.8cm]{iiiii}}
```

in the math mode the compiler returns no error but the compile does not allow it when I want to define it as a new command?

Comment: Without knowing the answer how do I know it is the problem with the name?  I thought it was the problem of the parameter 0.8cm..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definition of your macro is fine. The problem is that you cannot have numbers in the name of a macro, so if you change the name of your macro then all will be well:

[image]

Btw, rather than posting code snippets it is better to post a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228). In particular, the code should compile, unless that's the problem. This makes it much easier for other people to trouble shoot your problem and hence help you. Here is a MWE for your (corrected) code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\toeight}[1]{\xrightarrow{\mathmakebox[0.8cm]{#1}}}

\begin{document}

  $\toeight{f}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Got you Andrew!  I will follow your advice in my future posts! Many thanks for both the answer and the advice!

Answer (score 3):

Can't have a number as part of a command.

```
   \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\toeight}[1]{\xrightarrow{\mathmakebox[0.8cm]{#1}}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
    \toeight{xxx}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```